# Can't get gulp-jscs to write fixed files over originals

Tags: gulp, jscs, gulp-jscs

No problems running the **gulp-jscs** plugin to analyze my code using the following task. However when I add `fix:true`, nothing changes in the files and JSCS now acts like it isn't running at all... when I remove the object passed into the JSCS plugin and remove the `gulp.dest()` line, it will report code style issues.

So, it seems either passing in the `fix:true` or tying to write back the fixed files causes JSCS to short circuit internally... ideas?

```
var $ = require('gulp-load-plugins')({lazy: true});
gulp.task('vet', function () {
  log('Analyzing source with JSHint and JSCS');

  return gulp
    .src(config.allJs, {base: './'})
    .pipe($.jshint())
    .pipe($.jshint.reporter('jshint-stylish', {verbose: true}))
    .pipe($.jscs({fix:true}))
    .pipe(gulp.dest('./'));
});
```

Comment: Seems duplicated of: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30935717/gulp-jscs-autofix-doesnt-work

Answer (score 2):

## Update 2

I have found a simpler/cleaner way to do, just specify the base parameter

```
gulp.src(files, {base: './'})
```

then file.name will contain the full path so you can output to the current directory

```
gulp.dest('.')
```

so at the end:

```
gulp.src(files, {base: './'})
    .pipe(jscs({fix: true}))
    .pipe(jscs.reporter())
    .pipe(jscs.reporter('fail'))
    .pipe(gulp.dest('.'))
    .on('error', console.error.bind(console));
```

## Update 1

I have been tackling this problem with this piece of code:

```
var gulp = require('gulp');
var jscs = require('gulp-jscs');
var foreach = require('gulp-foreach');
var rimraf = require('gulp-rimraf');

gulp.task('jscs', () => {
return gulp.src(['file1.js', 'file2.js'])
    .pipe(foreach((stream, file) => {
        return stream
            .pipe(jscs({ fix: true }))
            .pipe(jscs.reporter())
            //.pipe(jscs.reporter('fail'))
            .pipe(rimraf())
            .pipe(gulp.dest(file.base));
    }));
});
```

dependencies:

```
npm install --save-dev gulp gulp-rimraf gulp-foreach gulp-jscs
```

Globally, gulp-foreach iterates over every src with its own stream, rimraf delete the file before writing on vinyl.base destination.

Let me know if it helps.